# Docker: Unable to find volume real location

Tags: macos, docker

I'm creating a Docker container with the following command:

```
docker run -v /data -d ubuntu
```

Afterwards I try to find out the real location of the volume with:

```
docker inspect 12345678
```

and it shows that it's in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/0ef2ed2715456b767fe52d38a316074c3da4a6fa82e4e42e5595c8dd8b5f0440/_data
ls: /var/lib/docker/volumes/0ef2ed2715456----/_data:`

But I don't actually have a `/var/lib/docker` directory.

What am I missing?

I'm using Docker 1.12 on Mac.

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.7.1
 Git commit:   6f9534c
 Built:        Thu Sep  8 10:31:18 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   23cf638
 Built:        Thu Aug 18 17:52:38 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/q/19234831/6309 help?

Comment: Docker for Mac is virtualized. The disk image location is noted in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37642236/2308683

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker on Mac runs a docker engine in a Linux VM, not your Mac OS, so you can't find the volume's mount point in your Mac OS file system. Please check my answer in this question: [Docker Named Volume location Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763115/docker-named-volume-location-mac/39763483#39763483)